# Titan DB graph to JSON

Tags: json, titan

Is there a way to create JSON out of TitanDB graph?

I can load a Titangraph to graphml , and then load it on Gephi and output as gexf/json
using some plugins. 
I was wondering if its possible to do this without involving Gephi at all, or as an alternative just use Gephi Java API to create the gexf/json.
I am partial to JSON since its of a smaller size.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [GraphSON](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/GraphSON-Reader-and-Writer-Library) as a JSON option.  From the Titan Gremlin Console you should be able to do:

```
gremlin> g.saveGraphSON("/tmp/my-graph.json")
```

UPDATE: For Titan 1.0 and TinkerPop 3.x, the syntax changes given changes to the TinkerPop 3.x API:

```
gremlin> graph.io(graphson()).writeGraph("/tmp/graph.json")
```

Where "graph" above refers to a `TitanGraph` instance.  There is more information about GraphSON in the TinkerPop 3 documentation found [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.1.1-incubating/reference/#graphson-reader-writer)

Comment: Thank you Stephen, I did it via the Java API.                 FileOutputStream outJSON = new FileOutputStream("E:\\titan-graph.json");        GraphSONWriter.outputGraph(graph, outJSON);

Comment: this did not work with titan 1.0 and tinkerpop 3.0. Can you please update the solution?

Comment: That worked, thanks. Can you tell me where you found out this Tinkerpop 3 documentation? I've been looking for it everywhere but can't seem to find it

Comment: perhaps you didn't notice it but the the link is embedded in the answer at the end of the last sentence